# XML scraping using nodeJs

Tags: node.js, xml, web-scraping, cheerio, tally

I have a very huge xml file that I got by exporting all the data from tally, I am trying to use web scraping to get elements out of my code using cheerio, but I am having trouble with the formatting or something similar. Reading it with fs.readFileSync() works fine and the console.log shows complete xml file but when I write the file using the fs.writeFileSync it makes it look like this:
[image: output image]

And my web scraping code outputs empty file:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const fs = require ('fs');



var xml = fs.readFileSync('Master.xml','utf8');

             const htmlC = cheerio.load(xml);
                     var list = [];
             list = htmlC('ENVELOPE').find('BODY>TALLYMESSAGE>STOCKITEM>LANGUAGENAME.LIST>NAME.LIST>NAME').each(function (index, element) {
                list.push(htmlC(element).attr('data-prefix'));
             })
             console.log(list)
             fs.writeFileSync("data.html",list,()=>{})
```

Comment: Just to confirm, when you say your web scraping code outputs an empty file, you mean at the end of execution, data.html is empty?

Answer (score 0):

You might try checking to make sure that Cheerio isn't decoding all the HTML entities. Change:

```
const htmlC = cheerio.load(xml);
```

to:

```
const htmlC = cheerio.load(xml, { decodeEntities: false });
```